# Defining x and y axis for drawImage - HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Trying to define the x and y axis for me has been a challenge:

```
    //get last x and y cordinates

 ...code   
    var p = $("#draggable");
    var offset = p.offset();
    var x = offset.left;
    var y = offset.top;
    //define new font size
    howMuch = startFontSize + howMuch;
    //define var with new font size
    startFontSize = howMuch;

    //define text font size and family
    ctx.font = howMuch + 'px ' + fFamily;
    //fill with the text
    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 100);
    //draw text
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

    ctx.drawImage(img, x,y, 500, 100);
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

....code
```

Here I am grabbing the x and y coordinates using offset() in JQuery and than defining those inside the drawImage() tags.  My issue is when this runs the text disappears?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Figured it out, thank you though!

Comment: Good work. You know you can accept your own answer?

Comment: Oh, after 2 days though? :P

Answer (score 0):

You know what guys I was getting the wrong `x` and `y`.  I have a container that holds the text and I was `"moving the text"` rather than the actual container so that's why the text was not visible, it went off the screen!  Silly me.